# Using oauth for creating twitter application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a twitter application in iphone using oauth. But my application request for:

```
oauth_consumer_key,
oauth_signature_method,
oauth_signature,
oauth_timestamp,
oauth_nonce,
oauth_version,
oauth_callback,
```

Please anyone help me how to create all these keys for my application.
In my twitter account xauth is disabled by default. So, how can I enable it in my application?

Comment: You're not really making clear what you are trying to do. What's up with these `oauth_...` values? Who's requesting them and where do they need to be created?

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely you need to enable xAuth. The Twitter API documentation, specifically the  [authentication guide](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) explain these parameters in more detail. Also have the [OAuth 1.0 spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/) open to refer to, even if you're using a third party library- you will save your sanity if you understand the mechanics of the token exchange.

Comment: what is signature in twitter oauth?

Comment: @Google, the signature is what you get when you pass your base string through a hash function, for twitter this is HMAC-SHA1. The oAuth provider uses this to check the authenticity of your API calls. Read the twitter auth guide for a better explanation.

Comment: to create signature which parameter i have to give?

Comment: @Google, the 'parameter' you sign is the base string. What results is your signature. Read the documentation for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read up about [OAuth](http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/). All the fields are part of the standard. Twitter will give you the first one (oauth_consumer_key), and the version number is always 1.0. (Version 2.0 is not yet complete and Twitter doesn't use it.) The others you need to calculate. Or at least find an open source library that does it for you.

As for enabling xAuth, you need to send a message to Twitter. Sounds like they're getting more and more strict about which apps they allow, though.

Comment: Hey @Stephen do you any library to generate just oauth_signature for iphone.

Comment: There are a few out there but I couldn't recommend any particular one since I ended up writing my own.

Comment: I too was able to make one but I dont know if that is correct or not, I will ask a question about this and add the link to that question here, will you be able to take a look at it. Thanks.....